# How to end a regular expression with a forward slash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem**

I am trying to match the hash part of a URL using Javascript.  The hash will have the format

```
/#\/(.*)\//
```

This is easy to achieve using "new RegExp()" method of creating a JS regular expression, but I can't figure out how to do it using the standard format, because the two forward slashes at the end begin a comment.  Is there another way to write this that won't start a comment?

**Example**

```
// works
myRegexp = new RegExp ('#\/(.*)\/');

// fails
myRegexp = /#\/(.*)\//
```

Comment: Where does this fail? `re = /#\/(.*)\//;` gives me `/#\/(.*)\//` on the console...

Comment: have you tested this to show it fails? what with? that seems like a stupid thing for a parser to do.

Comment: This is odd.  I can't see what I changed in my code, but copying this code across works fine. My bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am trying to match the hash part of a URL using Javascript.

Yeah, don't do that. There's a perfectly good URL parser built into every browser. Set an `href` on a location object (`window.location` or a link) and you can read/write URL parts from properties `hostname`, `pathname`, `search`, `hash` etc.

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href= 'http://www.example.com/foo#bar#bar';
alert(a.hash); // #bar#bar
```

If you're putting a path-like `/`-separated list in the hash, I'd suggest `hash.split('/')` to follow.

As for the regex, both versions work identically for me. The trailing `//` does not cause a comment. If you just want to appease some dodgy syntax highlighting, you could potentially escape the `/` to `\x2F`.

Comment: Oh, nice -- I'll use that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not starting a comment, just like two slashes in a string. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr2qb/2/